# php-read data from table into array and check with condition

Tags: php, c, postgresql

I've a program which can detect when 2 out of 3 temperature data in a single column is occurred or not and from there I can generate an error message. However this program is in C and I found it difficult in integrating C with php. So I think of directly convert the coding to php but the problem is I don't know how data from a table can be read into php as an array and check with the designed conditions as what I program in C below:

```
while (fscanf(fpt, "%f", &t) == 1)  // read until there are no more samples
{
total = 0;   // clear our counter
samples[2] = samples[1];   // toss out the old 3rd sample
samples[1] = samples[0];   // and shift them to make room for the
samples[0] = t;            // one we just read

for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
    if(samples[i] > 180)        // if any are over 180
        total++;                // increment our counter
if(total == 2) {                // if 2 of the 3 are over 180, we got 2 out of 3
    printf("2 out of 3 samples are greater than 180!\n");
    printf("1: %f\n2: %f\n3:%f\n", samples[2],samples[1],samples[0]); //this can be change to echo"..."
    break;
}
```

}

Now the problem I having is in the while loop, how php can read data into array as in the C program. Thank you for every single help.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is pretty much C for lazy people - who dont care about performance. As such for most libc functions there will be a PHP wrapper function in core - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php. Your program converts almost 1 to 1 into PHP, all you need is fopen() on the input source (change from php://stdin as appropriate):

```
<?php
  $samples = [0,0,0];
  $t = "";
  $fpt = fopen( "php://stdin", "r" ) or die ( "Failed open." );
  while (fscanf($fpt, "%f", $t) == 1)  // read until there are no more $samples
  {
    $total = 0;   // clear our counter
    $samples[2] = $samples[1];   // toss out the old 3rd sample
    $samples[1] = $samples[0];   // and shift them to make room for the
    $samples[0] = $t;            // one we just read

    for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++)
        if($samples[$i] > 180)        // if any are over 180
            $total++;                // increment our counter

    if($total == 2) {                // if 2 of the 3 are over 180, we got 2 out of 3
        printf("2 out of 3 samples are greater than 180!\n");
        printf("1: %f\n2: %f\n3:%f\n", $samples[2],$samples[1],$samples[0]); //this can be change to echo"..."
        break;
    }
  }
?>
```

Suppose this script is called fscanf.php. Test as follows:

```
echo -e "12.0\n.34.5\n.190.45\n450.45\n345.34" | php fscanf.php
```

Comment: erm in this script the data is open from an external file right? hmm, what if I need to call the data direct from the database system but read it into the similar array,how should I code it? I can connect to the database through the following command
$dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=name user=postgres password=123");

Comment: Oh, miss understood intent of question. You didnt say anything about a relational db. It should be trivial to convert above to read rows from a db . See http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php ...